# How do I insert a list of sequentially numbered (or different) strings concatenated together in emacs?

Tags: emacs

Basically I want the following in emacs:

`x = 52; while x > 0 { println("* Week #{x}\n"); x = x - 1; }`

This way I can generate a year's worth of something quickly in org mode, etc.

I'm sure it's a simple 'run this command and use lisp' answer, but I can't find it and I'm not *great* with emacs yet. I use spacemacs with emacs 24 and evil-mode on debian

Comment: Why did you tag this with [tag:vim] if it's a question about emacs?

Comment: I made a mistake! Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [Tiny](https://github.com/abo-abo/tiny), it is perfect for your case.

And here is a tiny snippet for you:  `m1\n5|* Week #{%d}`

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you're asking for: to provide a number `NUM` to a command and have it print lines `* Week N`, where `N` starts with `NUM` and goes down to `1`.

```el
(defun insert-my-strings (num)
  (interactive "N")
  (let ((form  (format "* Week %%%dd\n" (1+ (log num 10))))
        (p     num))
    (while (> p 0)
      (insert (format form p))
      (setq p  (1- p)))))
```

You invoke the command by binding it to a key or using `M-x insert-my-strings`.

With no prefix arg you are prompted to enter the number `NUM` you want.  Otherwise, provide the number `NUM` as a prefix arg to the command: `C-u NUM M-x  insert-my-strings`, where `C-u NUM` means to input NUM as the numeric prefix arg.

---

Or if you want this only for `NUM` = 52:

```el
(defun insert-weeks ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((p  52))
    (while (> p 0)
      (insert (format "* Week %2d\n" p))
      (setq p  (1- p)))))
```

Comment: Thank you, I've accepted this as it works and is quite clear.

Answer (score 1):

Same solution as Drew's, but using defuns `plusp` and `decf`:

```lisp
(let ((p 5))
  (require 'cl)        ; For `plusp' and `decf'
  (while (plusp p)
    (insert (format "* Week %2d\n" p))
    (decf p)))
```

Comment: You need to either (1) require library `cl` or (2) require library `cl-lib` and change `plusp` to `cl-plusp` and `decf` to `cl-decf`.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an example of an ad-hoc use-case, I recommend using keyboard macros (or, even more concisely, use the "Tiny" library as per zilongshanren's answer).

Using keyboard macros:

- <kbd>M-1</kbd><kbd><f3></kbd> (initialise the counter to 1)
- <kbd>RET</kbd> `* Week` <kbd><f3></kbd><kbd><up></kbd> (insert counter value)
- <kbd>M-5</kbd><kbd>M-2</kbd><kbd><f4></kbd> (execute a total of 52 times)

n.b. It's slightly simpler<sup>1</sup> to count upwards and just insert the lines in reverse order, but for counting downwards:

- <kbd>M-5</kbd><kbd>M-2</kbd><kbd><f3></kbd>
- `* Week` <kbd>M--</kbd><kbd><f3></kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>M-5</kbd><kbd>M-2</kbd><kbd><f4></kbd>

<sup>1</sup> in that you don't need to remember whether the counter adjustment/decrement takes effect before or after the insertion.